# Swift Network framework with TCP

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, network-programming

I'm making a simple test app using Swift Network framework. One server, one client (both iOS simulators), and successfully established tcp connection between them. I'm trying to send a series of short messages.

Server is sending strings made of natural numbers from 1 to 999. Each number is sent as separate Data, *isComplete* and *contentContext* default values are *true* and *.defaultMessage* correspondingly.

```
var count = 0

func send(data: Data) {
    self.connection.send(content: data, completion: .contentProcessed( { error in
        if let error = error {
            self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
            return
        }
        self.count += 1
        let newData = "\(self.count)".data(using: .utf8)!
        if self.count < 1000 {
            self.send(data: newData)
        }
        print("connection \(self.id) did send, data: \(newData as NSData)")
    }))
}
```

Client is receiving them...

```
private func setupReceive() {
    nwConnection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65536) { (data, contentContext, isComplete, error) in
        if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
            print("isComplete: \(isComplete)")
            print("isFinal: \(contentContext.isFinal)")
            let message = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("connection did receive, data: \(data as NSData) string: \(message ?? "-" )")
        }
        if let error = error {
            self.connectionDidFail(error: error)
        } else {
            self.setupReceive()
        }
    }
}
```

... but there is something wrong. Some messages look like their bytes are stuck together (for example consecutive messages "2", "3", "4", "5" could be received like a single message "2345")

For all received messages *isComplete* equals *false*  and *contentContext* property *isFinal* equals *true*, while *.defaultMessage.isFinal* should be equal to *false*.

For now, i'm stuck. Am i just using wrong parameters (I've tried various combinations, but none seems working to me)? Is NWConnection hideously changing messages while sending them?

How can one send a series of separate messages?

Comment: The first section of code looks odd.  You have a guy named 'data' as content.  You then create a new variable named 'data' several lines after that.

Comment: @ElTomato It's just a local variable. While in scope of function, it overrides external variables with the same name (like a function argument). But i will rename it, to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this `Network` framework. But from reading documentation, it seems like you are directly using the transport layer to transmit messages.

Without an application layer protocol, there probably isn't a way for the client to distinguish between different messages. For example, using http as your application protocol has different parameters in the request to identify if its a complete message or not (Content-Length, Content-Encoding, Transfer-Encoding etc...)(Hope an expert can confirm on this)

You may define you own simple protocol so that decoding is possible on client end. For example, you can wrap each message with `<Message>your-message</Message>` and use it to identify different messages at the client (you will face some drawbacks of something so simple along the way)

There are many things to consider when developing a custom protocol. Better do some reading on this subject if you are serious on it.

Upon further reading, it seems that the following receive is provided:

```
final func receiveMessage(completion: @escaping (Data?, NWConnection.ContentContext?, Bool, NWError?) -> Void)
```

... which is able to read complete data. The Discussion section will provide some valuable insight on transport type implications and framing logic required.

Comment: So you think it is not possible to send complete Data object on with NWConnection on TCP level without additional protocol. And we can only send raw byte stream without knowing where is message end. OK. But then what is  isComplete flag meaning? And why not all received bytes are combined, actually most messages are received as complete objects as expected?

Comment: Read the discussion section as I said (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/3020638-receivemessage). There is a method to receive a complete message using the above function rather that the one you use (which reads a range of bytes). The implications are detailed nicely in the Discussion section.

Comment: @jms Yes, i'm trying to use transport level directly. Not really sure about those http headers and their purpose - it could be integrity control or something else. But Apple docs (as i understand them) insist that i should be able to control completing messages using Network. Definition of 'isComplete' and 'isFinal' parameters states that they are made exactly for this task. I've considered a possibility to make a custom integrity protocol, but it just doesn't seems right, to make custom implementation for mechanic that is already built-in.

Comment: @jms As for receiveMessage() - seems that it’s checking the isComplete flag of received data chunk, and if it’s false, then chunk is stored, until we receive a chunk with isComplete == true, and then all stored chunks are combined to a single message. Really useful method, but it doesn’t solve the problem - isComplete is turning false on every chunk.